# Converting Rows to Columns from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to query a time attendance database that shows the following data from two tables

```
USERINFO
USERID   Name
1    Joe Bloggs

CHECKINOUT
USERID   CHECKTIME
1    27/05/2014 07:44
1    27/05/2014 13:50
1    28/05/2014 08:12
1    28/05/2014 16:27
1    29/05/2014 07:46
1    29/05/2014 16:30
1    30/05/2014 07:40
1    30/05/2014 15:59


Select dbo.USERINFO.NAME, dbo.CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME 
FROM dbo.USERINFO Inner Join dbo.CHECKINOUT on dbo.USERINFO.USERID = dbo.CHECKINOUT.USERID
Query results:
Name    CheckTime
Joe Bloggs  27/05/2014 07:44
Joe Bloggs  27/05/2014 13:50
Joe Bloggs  28/05/2014 08:12
Joe Bloggs  28/05/2014 16:27
Joe Bloggs  29/05/2014 07:46
Joe Bloggs  29/05/2014 16:30
Joe Bloggs  30/05/2014 07:40
Joe Bloggs  30/05/2014 15:59
```

What I want to see is something like this:

```
Name    CheckTime   ClockIn ClockOut
Joe Bloggs  27/05/2014  07:44:55    13:50:53
Joe Bloggs  28/05/2014  08:12:03    16:27:10
Joe Bloggs  29/05/2014  07:46:59    16:30:06
Joe Bloggs  30/05/2014  07:40:23    15:59:41
```

I tried all the advice on converting rows to columns in this site but I can't get it to work.

EDIT: 
Basically I tried PIVOT, XML method, CASE statement and COALESCE function but I get loads of error. I'm fairly new to SQL Server but have done PIVOT in MSAccess.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What specific advice did you follow? What did you try and where did you fail to get it to work? Because this appears as if it's just a normal Pivot you need to do, and there's tons of information online on how to do it that works brilliantly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+pivot

Answer (score 1):

the following Code will give you someting like this, hope this is what you want

**Name**    |    **ClockIn**  |   **ClockOut** 
Joe Bloggs |    2014-05-27 07:44:00.000  |  2014-05-27 13:50:00.000
Joe Bloggs |    2014-05-28 08:12:00.000  |  2014-05-28 16:27:00.000
Joe Bloggs |    2014-05-29 07:46:00.000  | 2014-05-29 16:30:00.000
Joe Bloggs |    2014-05-30 07:40:00.000  |  2014-05-30 15:59:00.000

```
    CREATE TABLE #PRERESULT(
    Name nvarchar(50),
    CheckTime datetime)

    INSERT INTO #PRERESULT
    VALUES
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-27 07:44'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-27 13:50'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-28 08:12'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-28 16:27'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-29 07:46'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-29 16:30'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-30 07:40'),
    ('Joe Bloggs',  '2014-05-30 15:59')


    CREATE TABLE #RESULT(
    name nvarchar(50),
    ClockIn datetime,
    ClockOut datetime)


    DECLARE @Day nvarchar(50)

    DECLARE C_Checktime CURSOR
    FOR

    SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(Checktime,'dd/MM/yyyy') as Checktime
    FROM #PRERESULT 

    OPEN C_Checktime

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_Checktime INTO @Day
    While (@@Fetch_status = 0)
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #RESULT
    SELECT a.name
    , b.CheckTime As ClockIn
    , a.CheckTime As ClockOut
    FROM #PRERESULT a JOIN #PRERESULT b 
    ON a.CheckTime > b.Checktime
    WHERE FORMAT(a.Checktime,'dd/MM/yyyy') = @Day
    AND FORMAT(b.Checktime,'dd/MM/yyyy') = @Day
    AND a.CheckTime <> b.CheckTime 

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_Checktime INTO @Day
    END

    CLOSE C_Checktime
    DEALLOCATE C_Checktime

    SELECT * FROM #RESULT

    DROP TABLE #PRERESULT
    DROP TABLE #RESULT
```

For Converting your Datetime Format to mine use:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, Checkdate, 103)
```

Hope this helps you, have a nice day

Etienne

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything like `PIVOT` or `XML`, just group by the date

```
SELECT UserID
     , DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, CHECKTIME), 0) CheckTime
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Min(CHECKTIME),108) ClockIn 
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Max(CHECKTIME),108) ClockOut
FROM   CHECKINOUT
GROUP BY UserID, DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, CHECKTIME), 0)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b485e/2)</kbd>